# fnil-like function in Clojure for defining output

Tags: clojure, null

In Clojure, the [fnil](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fnil) function can be used to wrap another function: if the argument of the wrapped function would be `nil`, the wrapper will change it to something else.

E.g. `((fnil * 0) nil) ; returns 0` However `(* nil 0)` would throw an NPE.

What I'm asking is if there is a similar, **built-in** function that modifies the output, in case the input is `nil`. (In other words, it does not even call the wrapped function, it just returns the default value instead.)

In other words, is there a built-in function equivalent to the following?

```
(defn ifnil [fun default]
      (fn [& args]
          (if (some nil? args) default (apply fun args))))


; ((ifnil * nil) 1 2 3) ; returns 6
; ((ifnil * nil) 1 nil 3) ; returns nil
```

N.B.: As always, "no, there is no such function" is also a valid answer (which I suspect, btw.)

Comment: I haven't seen that.

Comment: Your question is fine, but your example is poor: `(* nil)` returns `nil`, rather than throwing an exception. Multiplying `x` by no factors simply returns `x`, without verifying that `x` is a number.

Comment: @amalloy: thanks, you are right, I meant `(* nil 0)` (Indeed, `(* nil)` just returns `nil`. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a function, as far as I know. Your implementation looks well, so why not to use it in your code.

What may be improved here is a better name of the function: `ifnil` might be a bit confusing for your teammates or those who will support your code.

Also, you said `in case the input is nil`. But in your code, you check for at least one argument is `nil`. That differs slightly.

And one more thing, personally I'm not a fan of failing to defaults silently. Maybe, you'd better to validate the input data either manually or using schema/spec and write logs. Because `fnil` mostly used for non-existing keys with `update`/`update-in`. But you function tends to be rather a validator.

Comment: Rather than validator, my use case is multiplying two matrixes, where some elements might be missing (and thus `nil`).